# How to make visual studio automatically add files to the project?

Tags: git, solution-explorer, visual-c++-2013

Is there a way to make visual c++ automatically include all source files in a project's dir to a project? I want to see them in solution explorer, and include them in compilation. Not being able to do so becomes a problem when you are working with git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I stumbled upon it in a google search, so I'll add my solution for those future googlers.

In the project  file you can add the line: `<Compile Include="**/*.hpp" />`

This will add all c++ header files in any directory under the solution to the project.  You can specify the directories instead of the asterisk if you'd like to be more specific.

Comment: Doesn't this break once you add a file to a project through Visual Studio? It might even duplicate some files along the way...

Comment: @ravemir In my experience adding files goes smoothly.  However, removing them causes the proj file to revert back to it's original state.  If you really want to remove a file, you simply need to go delete it from the folder on disk.

Comment: That's exactly what I've been doing: just keep adding/removing files through explored, as opposed to VS. This is especially useful when managing NUnit iterative test cases based on files/folders.